# Will the power of sunchoke ruin plastic?

Tags: growth

I have some large PVC pipes near my sunchokes, so I was wondering if it's been known to damage PVC pipes.

Comment: Do you me an they are near underground PVC pipe? I don't think they are invasive, but many trees are. If a crack gets in the pipe a tree root can find it and work its way in there. But this usually happens more with perforated drain pipe around the base of a house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen this discussed.

However, I recently pulled my sunchokes out and was quite surprised at how small the root ball was, and how big the tubers were.

Pipes get damaged by invasive roots and these didn't look like those at all. And of course the pipes need to be damaged so that roots can enter. So I'd not worry about it.

Before roasting in solar oven
[image: Oiled and flavored sunchokes before baking]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of them on the PVC pipe?

Comment: No, I didn't take pictures